# Block AKS Public URL related to Microservices and keep them for internal communication

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-aks

I deployed my microservices on AKS Cluster and want to stop public access after deployment and want services to communicate internally. My main site should browse publically.
How we can stop public IPs to browse and force them to communicate internally?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, sorry but posed like this it's very hard to answer. Can you add a more concrete example?

Comment: Here Is What I wanted to ask. I have 3 microservices when I deployed them on AKS Cluster Using Load Balancer they expose publically by the IP AKS Load Balancer Provides So I want to block public IP and want microservices to communicate without a publiclly expose